# Modal popup in specific container instead root

Tags: antd

I need to load modal in specific div instead of root. I have noticed that one method called "getContainer". Can someone help me to show me the correct usage of 'getContainer' method? This is a specific usage question about [ant.design](https://ant.design/components/modal/)

Answer (score 1):

For example. If you have block `div` with `id="test"`, you can use this code for put Modal into this container:

```
<div id="test">div for mounting modal</div>
<Modal
  title="test window"
  visible={showNewMessageModal}
  getContainer={() => document.getElementById("modal-wrapper")}
>
modal content
</Modal>
```